# How Do I Access IBOutlets From Other Classes in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, properties, iboutlet

How do I access `IBOutlets` that have been created in another class? For example, if I have an `IBOutlet` in `Class A` how can I access in `Class B`? If I can not access `IBOutlets` from other classes what is a work-around?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to make your `IBOutlet` a `@property` and define a getter for that property via `@synthesize` or you can define your own getter, here's an example of the former:

```
@interface ClassA : NSObject {
   UIView *someView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *someView;
@end

@implementation ClassA

@synthesize someView;

...

@end
```

Then, in `ClassB`, you can do this:

```
@implementation ClassB 

- (void) doSomethingWithSomeView {
   ClassA *a = [ClassA new];
   UIView *someView = [a someView];
   //do something with someView...
}

...

@end
```